# Control Panel shows same application multiple times (twice)

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2017

For some reason, I appear to have visual studio twice on my machine. However, I don't know if I really do, or whether it's just what Control Panel shows

This is a screen shot of my control panel

[image]

However, if I look into

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\

I can see it exists only in this location. I  don't seem to have Visual Studio any where else! (for example, it isn't in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio).

A search on my computer for `devenv.exe` (which is the application exe) returns only 1 result.

Is there any way to understand why control panel thinks this ? I want to remove one but, I'm scared that it will remove Visual Studio totally from my computer

Comment: Could you look at the `Command line` column and tell what's the differences? You might see there more details about the running process.

Comment: What command line column? There isn't one?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Perhaps the comment was referring to the `Command line` column in the Windows 10 Task manager. If you right-click a column heading under certain tabs (`Processes`, `Startup`, and `Details` under `Select Columns`, I believe) the stated column appears as an option. In a similar fashion, there is also an optional `Location` column available in the main `Programs and Features` window (right-click and select the `More...` option). That said, at least for `Location`, this doesn't help with showing the location of VS 2015 and seems unlikely to have changed with VS 2017.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions As a total peanut gallery comment, regarding your issue, perhaps one is a dead entry for a prior installation on the same day (as I am gathering you might suspect). Purely as personal opinion, I would be hesitant to mess with it unless I knew it was causing an issue for the exact reason you specify (you might choose wrong and uninstall your current installation).

Comment: @Anaksunaman yes, that is my gut feeling as well. The issue I have is my hard drive is small on my Surface and if it's taking another 1.6gb of file space, I could with freeing it up. Seems though this is a very unique bug/issue

Comment: When I did eventually uninstall one of them, the other was also removed (well, it showed a white icon in control panel and when I went to remove it, the macine detected it already had been removed)